# What are the Dart update channels?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

On the [Dart Editor page](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/) we can choose between 2 channels : *dev* and *stable*. What are the differences between them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post of Rico Wind](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/mHNADU74_t0/t2mhCfhm9m0J) explains that very well :

> **dev** channel will be something like the integration builds we offered before, i.e., weekly or biweekly releases.
>
> **stable** channel will only get critical bug fixes and otherwise be updated to a new minor version with something like 6 week intervals (this is not a guarantee, some releases may come faster some may come slower).
>
> Dev channel will, as the name indicates, have a higher probability of containing bugs, but you will get access to new features/performance improvements faster.

See also the announcement : [Presenting Dart channels](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/announce/UXRMVmX_6EQ).

Comment: how is bleeding edge related to this. Is this building from source?

Comment: I asked the question and [got the answer](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/UXRMVmX_6EQ/_hNgAEo5lrwJ). You can get the raw, unsigned bits here: http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/dev/raw/latest/

Comment: The good place to get the raw version seems to be http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/be/raw/latest/

Comment: Question to the author of the answer: Your answer means that  impossible to downloads `REAL STABLE` version of the Dart  becuase "stable channel will only get critical bug fixes". That is if the Dart 1.0 has been released with some known bugs then the stable channel ensure only that the critical bug  has been fixes but the other bugs still can migrates from one version to another? Even if these bugs has been registered a long time ago but they are not considered by the developers as the critical bugs?