# Which version of Dart Platform use and how?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I asks these questions because I assume that the main page www.dartlang.org is similar to "download page" because possible direct `DOWNLOAD DART` (`without redirect to download page`)  from this page without requirement to read additional information.

When I want download Java I can read similar information on the download page.

```
Version 7 Update 45
```

This means that this is a version 7 with the 45 update. I assume it last stable.

When I want download Dart I can read similar information on the download page (www.dartlang.org).

```
CURRENT STABLE VERSION OF DART: 30188
```

How I can get information how many updates released after major version?

Is this means that Dart has `1.0 rev 30188`?

In my Editor (that I use) version is `version 1.0.1_r30657 (DEV)`. It downloaded automatically.

Which version I use?

I think it is not stable because `CURRENT STABLE VERSION OF DART is 30188`.

How to avoid in Editor to download unstable versions?

How to allow the Editor to download latest stable versions?

Or I must use two systems (possible virtual) separately. One for the production and another for the development?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the Dart update channels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090325/what-are-the-dart-update-channels)

Comment: Not possible duplicate of What are the Dart update channels? Because the main question is "Which version of Dart Platform use and how?".

Comment: And also possible download Editor from the main page www.dartlang.org,  where information about channels not present. So it is a question not about channels because this question point directly to main page of Dart langauge where no information about you wrote.

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin My answer to your comment in top of of my question. You can re-read it to understand why I ask it. It is not quite correct allow  direct download from the main page without given any additional information about another possible downloads.

Answer (score 1):

> How I can get information how many updates released after major version?

You'll have to ask Google, they're not really doing comprehensive release notes right now because it *just* went to version 1. In the future, major version changes might be tracked on the [language spec page](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/).

> I think it is not stable because `CURRENT STABLE VERSION OF DART is 30188`

Well, your version isn't considered stable because it's a dev release. A release can be stable even if it's not the most current.

> How to avoid in Editor to download unstable versions? How to allow the Editor to download latest stable versions?

Only download the current stable version provided by Google. Not sure how your editor is downloading something automatically, the Dart Editor downloads directly from dartlang.org are packaged with the specified version of the language.

For older builds, check this out - http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-editor-archive-integration/ .

Answer (score 1):

- Updates are not counted in Dart the way they are counted in Java
- 30188 is a continuous build number. Not every increment is a release. In fact between two updates differ usually by more than one build number.
- A stable version is never the most current. The most current are builds from source (bleeding edge) from the development branch.
- If you download the development version it updates itself with updates from the development channel. If you download a stable version it updates itself only with stable updates.
- You can change the configuration so that the editor doesn't download updates automatically.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the other answers: If you want to use the stable build, you have to download it from dartlang.org. You probably have the DEV version because you used the Editor before Dart went to 1.0:

> All existing users that has been with us from pre 1.0 days have been automatically updated to the dev channel.

https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/UXRMVmX_6EQ/CSEHZ5c_HBYJ

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have downloaded Dart Editor before the release of the first stable and you are updating it right from the Dart Editor environment. The version `1.0.1_r30657 (DEV)` you wrote is the unstable **dev release** (as it was before the release of the first stable) and **it automatically updates only to the dev releases.**

For the latest **stable release**, you should download the current stable version of Dart `1.0.0_r30188 (STABLE)` on the Dart Editor website https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/. **It automatically updates only to the stable releases.**

*P.S.: If you want to get back the dev version, the link is right under the stable download link on the Dart Editor website*